# Expression explanation

Tags: sql, expression, teradata

I'm now supporting a report that was developed by someone else.  The WHERE clause contains the following 2 statements.  I don't understand what each one does and what the individual parts of each one does.  Any help in understanding these statements would be greatly appreciated.  Thank You

```
and rd.system_ci_date >= ADD_MONTHS(date - EXTRACT(day FROM date) + 1,-1)
and  (rd.system_ci_date - rd.ci_date) DAY(4) > 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ADD_MONTHS(date - EXTRACT(day FROM date) + 1,-1)` returns the 1st day of the previous month, a slightly more efficient version is `ADD_MONTHS(date - (EXTRACT(day FROM date) - 1),-1)`

`(rd.system_ci_date - rd.ci_date) DAY(4)` returns the difference between both dates in an INTERVAL (which will fail if there are more than 9999 days inbetween). It's the same as `rd.system_ci_date - rd.ci_date` which returns an INT.

Maybe rewriting it to

```
and rd.system_ci_date >= ADD_MONTHS(date - (EXTRACT(day FROM date) -1) ,-1)
and rd.system_ci_date > rd.ci_date + 1
```

is a bit easier to understand

Comment: @dnoeth........Thank you.....does the Day(4) mean 9999 days?  Is there a Day(1), Day(2), Day(3), etc?  Thanks for your help

Comment: @Shaves: Yes, the `n` in `DAY(n)` specifies the number of digits, default is `2`. The maximum of 9999 is not really large, that's why nobody's using those Standard SQL INTERVALs :-)

Comment: @dnoeth.........Thank you.  I appreciate the time you've taken to help me understand these things.  I'm accountant that is being moved into more of a reporting role and am mostly self taught.  These forums have been a big help to me.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

**rd.system_ci_date** is the today's date

`ADD_MONTHS(date - EXTRACT(day FROM date) + 1,-1)` which will return the first day of the previous month.

`(rd.system_ci_date - rd.ci_date) DAY(4) > 1` which gives the difference.

`DAY(4)` defines 9999 days